# Android pinch zoom, ZoomOut and ZoomIn, in limit

Tags: android, touch, android-imageview, zooming, pinchzoom

I have already searched alot around here but haven't found a solution yet. So the thing is , I have a image 3000*3000 px, I set it to scale type matrix. Now I have only the left corner showing of the image. Now I don't want people to zoom in at this stage, only zoom out to a maximum of 'x' (Still have to see how much).
It's the imageview "kaart" that has to be zoomed.

**question :** How to let people only zoom out in the beginning and don't let them pass x ?and afterwards, don't let them zoom in more than the original size

i've tried with negative values , but that didn't work

Here is my code:

```
    // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

// max and min zoom
//private static final float MIN_ZOOM = 1.0f;
//private static final float MAX_ZOOM = 5.0f;
//scale = Math.max(MIN_ZOOM, Math.min(scale, MAX_ZOOM));

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;

int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF start = new PointF();
PointF mid = new PointF();
float oldDist = 1f;
String savedItemClicked;

ImageView view;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.kaart);
   view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.kaart);
   view.setOnTouchListener(this);
}



public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    dumpEvent(event);


    // Handle touch events here...
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
        //Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
        mode = DRAG;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
        oldDist = spacing(event);
        //Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
        if (oldDist > 10f) {
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            midPoint(mid, event);
            mode = ZOOM;
            //Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
        }
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        mode = NONE;
       // Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        if (mode == DRAG) {
            // ...
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY()
                    - start.y);
        } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
            float newDist = spacing(event);
           // Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);

            if (newDist > 10f) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                float scale = newDist / oldDist;

                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);

            }
        }
        break;
    }
    limitZoom(matrix);
    limitDrag(matrix);
    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    return true;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
            "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int action = event.getAction();
    int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
    if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
            || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
        sb.append("(pid ").append(
                action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
        sb.append(")");
    }
    sb.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
        sb.append("#").append(i);
        sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
        sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
        sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
        if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
            sb.append(";");
    }
    sb.append("]");
   // Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
}

/** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}

/** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}
}
```

Hope someone can help me. I would really apreciate it.

**EDIT**

I have added 2 functions i found somewhere.

```
    private void limitZoom(Matrix m) {

    float[] values = new float[9];
    m.getValues(values);
    float scaleX = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
    float scaleY = values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];
    if(scaleX > MAX_ZOOM) {
        scaleX = MAX_ZOOM;
    } else if(scaleX < MIN_ZOOM) {
        scaleX = MIN_ZOOM;
    }

    if(scaleY > MAX_ZOOM) {
        scaleY = MAX_ZOOM;
    } else if(scaleY < MIN_ZOOM) {
        scaleY = MIN_ZOOM;
    }

    values[Matrix.MSCALE_X] = scaleX;
    values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y] = scaleY; 
    m.setValues(values);
}
```

and

```
private void limitDrag(Matrix m) {
    float[] values = new float[9];
    m.getValues(values);
    float transX = values[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float transY = values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];
    float scaleX = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
    float scaleY = values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.kaart);
    Rect bounds = iv.getDrawable().getBounds();
    int viewWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    int viewHeight = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

    int width = bounds.right - bounds.left;
    int height = bounds.bottom - bounds.top;

    float minX = (-width + 20) * scaleX; 
    float minY = (-height + 20) * scaleY;

    if(transX > (viewWidth - 20)) {
        transX = viewWidth - 20;
    } else if(transX < minX) {
        transX = minX;
    }

    if(transY > (viewHeight - 80)) {
        transY = viewHeight - 80;
    } else if(transY < minY) {
        transY = minY;
    }

    values[Matrix.MTRANS_X] = transX;
    values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] = transY; 
    m.setValues(values);
}
```

I have to call these functions right after the switch case and just before is set the imagematrix on my view. (I have added this to my previous code here above)

maybe this isn't the best solution , but it works .

Comment: question : How to let people only zoom out in the beginning and don't let them pass x ? and afterwards, don't let them zoom in more than the original size

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code, you keep saving the matrix as a way to remember what was the state of the zoom and scroll (which could be done by one matrix alone, but maybe you're doing other manipulations).

This way, every action effects are relative to the last state, and it's difficult to set an absolute limit to the zoom (and scroll too): to get their absolute values, you'd have to call matrix.getValues() and pick the values from the array it returns.

Try instead saving the current x-scroll, y-scroll and zoom, and at every action check if their updated values (that now remain absolute) would be inside your limits; if so actually update them, then reset the matrix and set the new scroll/zoom values.

(also, consider the use of GestureDetector and ScaleGestureDetector)

Comment: let us know if this answer helped you.